# Oracle APEX Interactive Grid - Can I Create default Control Break view?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

Does anyone know if it's possible for me to create a Control Break view as the default view when a user views the page?

What i mean is, instead of viewing all 1000 rows of a report, I would like it defaulted to Control Break display it by a certain column.

Perhaps see the image of the default view that i require. 
http://prntscr.com/hgm6bw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Put your control break on and then click `Actions > Save Report` then save as `default report settings > primary report`.